# How config url in Kaminari pagination? '.json' appended automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, pagination, format, kaminari

Load table with Kaminari pagination using AJAX.
The pagination itself is using AJAX as well.

In my controller:

```
def update_user_list
  modal = render_to_string('tables/_user_table', :layout => false, :formats=>[:html]).html_safe
  data = {
    :table => modal
  }
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => data }
  end
end
```

In tables/_user_table

```
# Table part and content notrelated
<%= paginate @users, :params => {:controller => 'product', :action => 'more_users'}, :remote => true, :theme => 'twitter-bootstrap-3' %>
```

The response JSON of update_user_list looks like:

```
{
  table=" // the table part
          // the pagination part shows as follows
          <li class="page"><a href="/product/more_users.json?page=3&amp;user_subgroup_id=1" data-remote="true">3</a></li>
          <li class="page"><a href="/product/more_users.json?page=4&amp;user_subgroup_id=1" data-remote="true">4</a>
        "
}
```

What I want is to remove ".json" in the url.

If I just render tables/_user_table without AJAX, not in a JSON object, it doesn't have ".json" in the url.

version:
rails: 3.2.17
kaminari: 0.13.0
bootstrap-kaminari-views: 0.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the problem. It's actually not included in the question.

```
$.ajax({
   url: '<%= user_product_index_url %>.json',
   success: function(data) {
      // not important......
   });
```

remove ".json" here solve the problem...